# how to pass MVC model to a UI-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a Angular/bootstrap modal to edit MVC ApplicationUser scaffolded views. I have a found a few examples, they are mostly jquery. I found one that works well using jquery-ui. I want to be consistent with my modals so I need to make it work with angular-ui or plain bootstrap. I am not sure how this is calling the MVC controller for the data binding.

Working Jquery-ui example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Edit Customer',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 355,
            width: 400,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load(url);
            },
        });
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
      <tr>
       <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
        </td>
       <td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "editDialog" })|
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
     </td>
     </tr>
       }
      </tbody>

 <div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none"> </div>
```

Here is how I use angular to open a modal with a api call.

```
 $scope.editLocation = function (id) {
        $scope.close();
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'get', url: '/api/Locations/' + id })
                .success(function (model) {
                    deferred.resolve(model);
                    $scope.model = model;
                }).error(function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                }).then(function () {
                    $modal.open({
                        templateUrl: "EditLocationModal.html",
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceController',
                        resolve: {
                            model: function () {
                                return $scope.model;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

UPDATE

```
$scope.editUser = function (id) {

            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: "Modals/ApplicationUserModal.html",
                controller: 'ModalInstanceController',
                resolve: {
                    model: function () {
                        return $scope.model;
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

View

```
 <div class="card-body card-padding" ng-controller="ApplicationUserController">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Full Name</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         @foreach (var item in Model)
             {
               <tr>
                <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { ng_click = "editUser(item.Id)" })
                </td>
               </tr>
             }
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

UPDATE 2
This syntax

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { ng_click = "editUser(" + item.Id + ")" })
```

is throwing this error.

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'bc05f5' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 12 of the expression [editUser(87bc05f5-35c2-4278-a528-b7e237922d4e)] starting at [bc05f5-35c2-4278-a528-b7e237922d4e)].
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=bc05f5&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=12&p3=editUser(87bc05f5-35c2-4278-a528-b7e237922d4e)&p4=bc05f5-35c2-4278-a528-b7e237922d4e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure how this is calling the MVC controller for the data
>   binding.

Just to clue you in on the interesting parts

```
// 1. here it binds a "click" event to all elements with class "editDialog"
$(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) { 
    // 2. here it fetches the HREF attribute of that element
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
        title: 'Edit Customer',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 355,
        width: 400,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            // 3. And here it loads that HREF attribute in the modal
            $(this).load(url);
        },
    });
    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

That's basically all of the "data binding" going on in the jquery version. As you can see it's really not anything fancy.

You'd probably like to do something more elegant, like setting up an angular directive for your `editDialog` or somesuch.

EDIT:
I re-read how you init your modal and if I understood everything correctly you should be able to do something like this (not razor-savvy enough to be 100% on the syntax but you get the idea)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", 
   new { id = item.Id }, 
   new { ng_click = "editUser('" + @item.Id + "')" })
```

Also, you might or might not need to scope `editUser` inside `ng-click`.

Comment: See my updated answer and see if that works for you. If you absolutely need to load an entire URL like jquery does you'll need an iframe inside your modal and that just seems unnecessary.

Comment: it definitely  makes more sense on how it works but I am still not sure how to replace the jquery-ui modal with a bootstrap modal

Comment: the ng-click is not triggering function in controller

Comment: Then they may not be operating under the same scope. Did you try just alerting or logging something from the method to see that it really doesn't fire? Also, like I said, I'm not 100% that my Razor syntax is correct.

Comment: just updated post. yes i tried with alert. and forgive me if i am completely lost on what to do here. its been a long day

Comment: Maybe you need to `ng_click = "editLocation(" + @item.Id + ")"`? I'm thinking scope issue in any case though. You can try omitting the var completely `ng_click = "editLocation()"` until you can make sure it fires

Comment: the ng_click throws errors. I do not think there can be any spaces or dashes.

Comment: How about `ng_click = "ApplicationUserController.editLocation()"`? Assuming `ApplicationUserController` is where the method is scoped. In any case, it's doable this way. It's just about finding the right scope and Razor syntax.

Comment: it is scoped to that controller. i even double checked to make sure that script file was being loaded. I think the issue is with the ng_click. I am trying to see what the work around is

Comment: ok, after some sleep i can think. this is the right syntax to hit that modal function. needed to insert null in the third argument. now the issue is getting the data to bind. using breakpoint in controller i can see the id being passed into modal function is undefined.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { ng_click = "editUser(item.Id)" })

Comment: Aaah, then the syntax using `+` is correct, I just thought the id was a number for some reason. It's a string so you need to have string quotes around it. This should work: `ng_click = "editLocation('" + @item.Id + "')"`. Updated my answer with the (should be) working code.

Answer (score 0):

> This code to show bootstrap popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href,function(){
            $('#myModal').modal({
                   keyboard: true
              },'show');
              bindForm(this);
        });
           return false; 
    });

    function bindForm(dialog){
    $('form',dialog).submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
          url:this.action,
          type:this.method,
          data:$(this).serialize(),
          success: function(result){
              if(result.success)
    {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      $('#YourFormId').load(result.url);
      }
      else
      {
    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
      bindForm(dialog);
      }  
    }
    });
    return false;
    )};
    </script>
```

**In your parent view:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->


  </div>
</div>
```

In Edit in popup build the code into

```
  <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            //Your heading
          <div class="modal-body">
            //your body content
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
           //your footer
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Im kind of confused on the last part. where does that go?

Comment: which part of get into popup combine ur code into that. @texas697

Comment: This is a jquery solution, which OP already has. They asked specifically for a non-jquery solution.

Answer (score -1):

Example for delete with bootstrap modal and mvc model:(asp.net mvc6)
html page :

```
<div ng-controller="CustomersCtrl">
//template for modal with bootstrap
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#54a0fc !important;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h3>Delete</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name : </td>
                <td>{{customer.LastName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name : </td>
                <td>{{customer.FirstName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#54a0fc !important;">
    <button ng-click="delete(customer.CustomerID)" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Delete</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

in your controller think to add ['ui.bootstrap'] in your app.js:

```
CustomersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$modal'];

function CustomersCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $modal) {

 //function to open Delete modal
$scope.openDelete = function (id) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'Modals/Customers/delete.html',
            controller: $scope.modalDelete,
            //matches of the id of your item to recover object model in the controller of the modal
            resolve: {
                id: function () {
                    return id
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //controller of the modal. Inside you can recover your object with ajax request
    $scope.modalDelete = function ($scope, $modalInstance, id) {
        if (angular.isDefined(id)) {
            var reqGetCustomer = $http({ url: '/api/Customers/' + id, method: 'GET' });
            reqGetCustomer.success(function (dataResult) {
                $scope.customer = dataResult;
            });
        } else { alert('id is undefined'); }
        //function to close modal
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    }

    $scope.delete = function (id) {
        var customer = getCustomer(id);
        var reqDeleteCustomer = $http({ url: '/api/customers/' + id, method: 'DELETE' });
        reqDeleteCustomer.success(function (dataResult) {
            $scope.cancel();
        });
        $scope.customers = getListCustomers();
    }
 }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: This is just a copypasta of your own code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/31743478/78639 . This isn't relevant to the question at all.